# How can we automatically download PDF files in C# winform

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf, download

I have a C# Winforms app that runs the `WebBrowser` control to automatically login, navigate through some pages, and ultimately arrive to page that displays a PDF. I would like to automatically save this PDF whenever I arrive to this page but I have been unable to do this automatically.

Is there a way to automatically click "save" in the `webBrowser1.ShowSaveAsDialog()` window? Or is there another way to save the PDF that I have successfully displayed in the web browser?

Comment: It's probably easier to ask the user login info and use http sessions with cookies to log in and download the file in back-end. Also, I think the WebBrowser control is based on ancient IE...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use the WebClient (System.Net)?

```
    string FileName = @"C:\Temp\Test.pdf";
    string PDFUrl = "https://www.uni-trier.de/fileadmin/urt/doku/csharp/v60/csharp6.pdf";

    WebClient client = new WebClient();

    client.DownloadFile(PDFUrl, FileName);

    FileInfo PDFFile = new FileInfo(FileName);
```

You maybe have to look with Proxy-Authentication.